# Using UIImagePickerController for multiple uiimageviews. (Using more than one UIButton)

Tags: iphone, xcode, uiimageview, uibutton, uiimagepickercontroller

I have 2 uiimage views (imageview & imageview2)  and 2 uibuttons (useCameraRoll & useCameraRoll2) I have implemented code to set the images on these views using the 2 buttons.

imageview works fine along with its button useCameraRoll, but when i set an image using useCameraRoll2 it changes the image of imageview and not imageview2.

Code for view/button 1:

```
- (IBAction) useCameraRoll: (id)sender
{
    if ([self.popoverController isPopoverVisible]) {
        [self.popoverController dismissPopoverAnimated:YES];
    } else {
        if ([UIImagePickerController isSourceTypeAvailable:
             UIImagePickerControllerSourceTypeSavedPhotosAlbum])
        {
            UIImagePickerController *imagePicker =
            [[UIImagePickerController alloc] init];
            imagePicker.delegate = self;
            imagePicker.sourceType =
            UIImagePickerControllerSourceTypePhotoLibrary;
            imagePicker.mediaTypes = [NSArray arrayWithObjects:
                                      (NSString *) kUTTypeImage,
                                      nil];
            imagePicker.allowsEditing = NO;

            self.popoverController = [[UIPopoverController alloc]
                                      initWithContentViewController:imagePicker];

            self.popoverController.delegate = self;

            [self.popoverController presentPopoverFromRect:((UIButton *)sender).bounds inView:sender permittedArrowDirections:UIPopoverArrowDirectionAny animated:YES];

            newMedia = NO;
        }
    }
}





#pragma mark -
#pragma mark UIImagePickerControllerDelegate

-(void)imagePickerController:(UIImagePickerController *)picker
didFinishPickingMediaWithInfo:(NSDictionary *)info


{
    [self.popoverController dismissPopoverAnimated:true];
    NSString *mediaType = [info
                           objectForKey:UIImagePickerControllerMediaType];
   // [self dismissModalViewControllerAnimated:YES];
    if ([mediaType isEqualToString:(NSString *)kUTTypeImage]) {
        UIImage *image = [info
                          objectForKey:UIImagePickerControllerOriginalImage];

        self.imageView.image = image;
        if (newMedia)
            UIImageWriteToSavedPhotosAlbum(image,
                                           self,  
                                           @selector(image:finishedSavingWithError:contextInfo:),
                                           nil);
    }
    else if ([mediaType isEqualToString:(NSString *)kUTTypeMovie])
    {
        // Code here to support video if enabled
    }
}
```

code for view/button 2:

```
- (IBAction) useCameraRoll2: (id)sender
{
    if ([self.popoverController2 isPopoverVisible]) {
        [self.popoverController2 dismissPopoverAnimated:YES];
    } else {
        if ([UIImagePickerController isSourceTypeAvailable:
             UIImagePickerControllerSourceTypeSavedPhotosAlbum])
        {
            UIImagePickerController *imagePicker2 =
            [[UIImagePickerController alloc] init];
            imagePicker2.delegate = self;
            imagePicker2.sourceType =
            UIImagePickerControllerSourceTypePhotoLibrary;
            imagePicker2.mediaTypes = [NSArray arrayWithObjects:
                                      (NSString *) kUTTypeImage,
                                      nil];
            imagePicker2.allowsEditing = NO;

            self.popoverController2 = [[UIPopoverController alloc]
                                      initWithContentViewController:imagePicker2];

            self.popoverController2.delegate = self;



            [self.popoverController2 presentPopoverFromRect:((UIButton *)sender).bounds inView:sender permittedArrowDirections:UIPopoverArrowDirectionAny animated:YES];

            newMedia = NO;
        }
    }
}


#pragma mark -
#pragma mark UIImagePickerControllerDelegate

-(void)imagePickerController2:(UIImagePickerController *)picker2
didFinishPickingMediaWithInfo:(NSDictionary *)info2
{
    [self.popoverController2 dismissPopoverAnimated:true];
    NSString *mediaType2 = [info2
                           objectForKey:UIImagePickerControllerMediaType];
    // [self dismissModalViewControllerAnimated:YES];
    if ([mediaType2 isEqualToString:(NSString *)kUTTypeImage]) {
        UIImage *image2 = [info2
                          objectForKey:UIImagePickerControllerOriginalImage];

        self.imageView2.image = image2;
        if (newMedia2)
            UIImageWriteToSavedPhotosAlbum(image2,
                                           self,  
                                           @selector(image:finishedSavingWithError:contextInfo:),
                                           nil);
    }
    else if ([mediaType2 isEqualToString:(NSString *)kUTTypeMovie])
    {
        // Code here to support video if enabled
    }
}
```

I have checked that all the connections in interface builder are connected to the right view.

Does anybody know why this is going wrong

Regards

Comment: anybody have an idea? this has been here for 2 months

Comment: If my answer solved your problems maybe you should accept my answer. Otherwise please add a comment to tell what the solution was.

Answer (score 4):

I think that your problem may come from your delegate : your 2 UIImagePickerController use the same delegate, "self". The following method :

```
-(void)imagePickerController2:(UIImagePickerController *)picker2 didFinishPickingMediaWithInfo:(NSDictionary *)info2
```

is actually never called and is not a valid declaration for the `UIImagePickerControllerDelegate`.

You will need to distinguish which action was at the origin of your picker and update the proper image accordingly in the code of your single delegate method.

Maybe you could create an instance variable :

```
UIImageView *_currentPickerTarget
```

Then set this variable just before presenting the picker in every case :

```
- (IBAction) useCameraRoll: (id)sender {
    (...)
    _currentPickerTarget = imageView;
}

- (IBAction) useCameraRoll2: (id)sender {
    (...)
    _currentPickerTarget = imageView2;
}
```

And then in your delegate method you simply update the `_currentPickerTarget` by replacing :

```
self.imageView.image = image;
```

by

```
_currentPickerTarget.image = image;
```

in the `-(void)imagePickerController:(UIImagePickerController *)picker
didFinishPickingMediaWithInfo:(NSDictionary *)info` function.

Hope this will help.
Christophe